# Minimization of Inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation.

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=1$$

Where $x_1$ is the largest, $x_2$ is the second largest and so on. We have ten triplet combinations of these values which we can create. We apply the triangle inequality to the triplets. For example,

$$x_1>x_2+x_3$$

$$x_2>x_3+x_4$$...etc.

What is the minimum amount of the ten inequalities which can be satisfied. Is it possible that all ten of the inequalities cannot be satisfied?

Comment: If your question is based on another one, please put the link back to the [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2529948). In many cases, this will help answerers understand more about the question and what has been done.

Comment: Your triangle inequalities have the wrong directions. For example, for $x_1,x_2,x_3$, the triangle inequality is $x_1 < x_2 + x_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible for no triangle inequalities to be satisfied.

For example, let
$$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) =  (16t,8t,4t,2t,t)$$
with $t$ positive, but not yet specified.

It's easily seen that for those $5$ values, no $3$ distinct values can be used as lengths to form a triangle.

Now just solve the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 1\;$for $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Example :
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_1= \frac{17}{38},x_2= \frac{10}{38},x_3= \frac{6}{38},x_4= \frac{3}{38},x_5= \frac{2}{38}.
\end{eqnarray*}
One can rapidly verify that $x_i> x_j+x_k$ for $i<j<k$.